# Should I use Django's Admin feature?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm building a Django-based review website where public users create all of the content on the site. Users create reviews for given items and they also create the items themselves that will be reviewed (providing a description and brief summary of the item, along with a few tags).

My question is this: Should I be using Django's admin features for this website (as in, exposing admin controls to the public users)? Or should I just stick with normal forms? I'm not too familiar with the admin-aspect of Django, and so far I've just been using forms for the website, but I've seen a lot of people talking about Django's admin features, and I'm starting to wonder if I should be using them.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe. If the admin functionality covers most of what you want to offer, there's no reason why you shouldn't use it as a starting point.

django.contrib.admin is an application like any other, and provides basically a CRUD interface to your models. Access can be controlled via groups/permissions, just like you would for an application you write yourself. You can give full access to a model with a one-liner, but obviously will have to configure properly when opening up to others.

See also my question
[Django AdminSite/ModelAdmin for end users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531858/django-adminsite-modeladmin-for-end-users)
and similar questions [Exposing django admin to users. Harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077647/exposing-django-admin-to-users-harmful/6084927) and [How to make Django admin site accessed by non-staff user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022551/how-to-make-django-admin-site-accessed-by-non-staff-user/5573686)

Regarding arguments about the "intended use" of the admin, please note Django's security update at the end of last year: http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2010/dec/22/security/ regarding querystring parameters in object lists. Such an update (quote: "an attacker with access to the admin [...]") is a clear indication that the admin's implementation of the permission system is being constantly scrutinized.

Answer (score 6):

No. The django admin is not intended for any end-user.

The django admin feature is intended to assist the website developer, and that is all.  Even usage by site administrators is contra-indicated, although in practice most small sites get away with it since they're only talking a few people who can call on the developer personally if they get into trouble.

For your purposes, the review items and the workflow in creating the items is a critical part of your application feature set. The admin will give you ideas, but it would be a mistake to attempt to build your application upon it.

Comment: Django admin is meant for site administrators. It's to be used like any normal website backend, where site administrators can add and moderate the website. Nowhere is the documentation is it said that is is meant only for "web developers"

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't expose the admin interface to regular users. You can use the authentication and user-management side (for your purposes), but it's usually best practice to give users a separate way to manage their objects. You also don't run as much of a risk of granting the wrong privileges to users (or allowing them to grant their own).

Have a read though the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) if you want a better overview about what it can do.